# Opening a window over a grid in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop-application, desktop

Hello everyone  i have been working on a  wpf  project from some  time & i  got stuck at on point. here is the situation.... i m using a grid to show the data & on the double clicking on a grid row a new window pop ups to edit the same  data as one can see  in the first snapshot.
The problem is this when the pop up comes out it disables the whole background window. & we can move it to anywhere on the screen.[image: As you can see in this picture.]

What i want that when this pop up comes out it must be inside the parent grid on which i m showing the data & it should be fixed...one can see the desired output in the following image ....![image]

[check this link  to see this demo
 [http://demo.timetrex.com/interface/flex/?user_name=demoadmin1&password=demo]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: For Implementation of above u had to add your grid into  seperate page and then you need to open this page in tab or some where else in this page and had to set newly created page or window to  owner of your opening page so it will not show content other then your newly  created page  deemed and hope it will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up windows behavior as you have described can be explained by opening Modal Window using `ShowDialog()` method in WPF. You can open it as regular window using `Show()` method if necessary.

More details in MSDN ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope this will help. Regards,